# How do I implement Android Ice Cream Sandwich settings button UI?

Tags: android

The Settings screen on ICS has buttons (or something clickable) that looks like text separated by dividers, like so: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html, specifically http://developer.android.com/design/media/settings_overflow.png .

I can implement this in a variety of ways, but is there a standard way to use the Android API to do it?

Comment: There are a couple of dozen images on the page that you link to. Perhaps you might consider embedding in your question the actual image that you are interested in.

Comment: You're right, I went back to try it out on my phone, and it is ListView. One can even click on items like "Build Number" that flash when clicked but do nothing. I would prefer to do something more clever, like only make some items clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PreferenceActivity` ([JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)) is the class you want to work with.

The javadoc contains a full-featured example, check it out.